# How do I make my layer search pull the correct information?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, feature-layer, search

I am creating a web application with a Layer Search. Currently when I search the map, it brings up a state or parish but I would like it to go into more details and bring up the candidate's name for that state. It does open the results table and a message does pop up to say 1 result was found but I want the 1 result to show in the table. Is this possible? I want the pop up info to automatically display when the search is entered and a result is found. Each candidate is unique so it can only pull one result for each entry ( each candidate is only assigned one state). I will attach some code and screenshots so you can see exactly what I am referring to.

[image: So my search parameter was "James Robertson" and the result table did open to show that there was 1 result to match but it did not pop up in the results table so I could click on it or anything. How can I make it show in the result table so it can be easily seen.]

So my search parameter was "James Robertson" and the result  table did open to show that there was 1 result to match but it did not pop up in the results table so I could click on it or anything. How can I make it show in the result table so it can be easily seen.

Please see my code pen for code:

https://codepen.io/chesouye/pen/VwgqXEm

```
     graphicLayerSearch = new GraphicsLayer();

   //MAP INSTANCE
    map = new Map({
        basemap: "topo-vector",
        layers: [featureLayer, parish, graphicLayerSearch],//[ resultsLabelLayer,  graphicLayerSearch ],
        logo: false
      });

    //MAP VIEW OPTIONS
     view = new MapView({
        container: "map",
        map: map,
        zoom: 10,
        center: [-77.2627, 18.0927]
      });


 toggleLoading();
           var searchType = $('input[name="typer"]:checked').val();
          var searchString = stringFix($('#top-band-search').val().trim());
          var queryTask = new QueryTask({url: "https://services6.arcgis.com/3R3y1KXaPJ9BFnsU/arcgis/rest/services/GE_2020/FeatureServer/41"});
          var query = new Query();
          query.returnGeometry = true;
          query.outFields = ["*"];
          if(searchType === "cons"){
            query.where = "CONST LIKE '%"+searchString+"%'";
          }else{
            query.where = "JLP_CAN_1 LIKE '%"+searchString+"%' OR "
                         +"PNP_CAND LIKE '%"+searchString+"%' OR "
                         +"IND_A_CAN LIKE '%"+searchString+"%' OR "
                         +"INDB_CAND LIKE '%"+searchString+"%' OR "
                         +"INDC_CAND LIKE '%"+searchString+"%'";
          }
          query.outSpatialReference = view.extent.spatialReference;

            if(!searchString){
                if(detectIE() === -1){
                    //modalWindow.text = 'Please enter some text to search for';
                    //modalWindow.makeModal();
                }else{
                    alert('Please enter some text to search for');
                }
                $('#top-band-search').addClass('focus-error');
                $('#top-band-search').focus();
                toggleLoading();
            return false;
            }
           // When resolved, returns features and graphics that satisfy the query.
          queryTask.execute(query).then(function(results){
             var count = results.features.length;
             var resultsArray = results.features;
             graphicsArray = [];
             var resultsContainer = $('#data-search-results-container');
             var state = resultsContainer.attr('isOpen');

              if(state === 'true'){
                  var string = (count === 63)?"....":searchString;
                    $('#data-search-results-info')
                        .html("Found <b>" + count + "</b> results matching <br> <center><b>\"" + string + "\"</b></center>");
                        resultsContainer.attr('isOpen', true);
             }else{
                resultsContainer.animate({left: "0px"}, 1000,
                 function(){
                     var string = (count === 63)?"....":searchString;
                    $('#data-search-results-info')
                        .html("Found <b>" + count + "</b> results matching <br> <center><b>\"" + string + "\"</b></center>");
                        resultsContainer.attr('isOpen', true);

                     });
             }


                var listContainer = $('#data-search-results-list ul');
                listContainer.empty();
                for(var i = 0; i < resultsArray.length; i++){
                    var feature = resultsArray[i];
                    var geo = feature.geometry;
                    var attr = feature.attributes;
                    
                    // Add the geometry and symbol to a new graphic
                     var polygonGraphic = new Graphic({
                                            id: i,
                                            geometry: geo,
                                            symbol: fillSymbol,
                                            attributes: attr,
                                            popupTemplate: new PopupTemplate({title:"{CONST}",content: popTemplate}),
                                            layer: graphicLayerSearch
                                          });
                                          console.log(attr);
                    graphicsArray.push(polygonGraphic);
                    listContainer.append(listItem(i,attr));
                    dataArray[i] = attr;
                }

                addGraphics(view,graphicsArray);
                punchQuerySite(searchString);
          }).catch(function(error){
              console.log(error);
          });
```

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you want. Do you want popup info to be displayed inside the sidebar or do you want popup to open automatically? And what in the case there are several results from search, not only one? Please edit your question  with additional info.

Comment: I want the pop up info to automatically display when the search is entered and a result is found. Each candidate is unique so it can only pull one result for each entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really a GIS related question but purely HTML/JS related one, but anyway ...

All that has to be done to have popup automatically opened for the search result(s) is to put `formatPopup(attr);` call as the last step in the below loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < resultsArray.length; i++){
  var feature = resultsArray[i];
  var geo = feature.geometry;
  var attr = feature.attributes;
  
  // Add the geometry and symbol to a new graphic
   var polygonGraphic = new Graphic({
    id: i,
    geometry: geo,
    symbol: fillSymbol,
    attributes: attr,
    popupTemplate: new PopupTemplate({title:"{CONST}",content: popTemplate}),
    layer: graphicLayerSearch
  });
  console.log(attr);
  graphicsArray.push(polygonGraphic);
  listContainer.append(listItem(i,attr));
  dataArray[i] = attr;
  formatPopup(attr);
}
```

This of course means that if there are several results, several popups will be opened one over the other.

Here is how it looks like when there is one result:

[image]

Comment: Okay thank you much for assisting, it really does mean alot. I just want to know, what if instead of formatting it to popup the results, when a name is searched for it brings up the info just like before but puts the name of the candidate below or beside it to show that the person is in that state. Eg. you search for "James" and the results look something like "ST. THOMAS WESTERN -  MR. JAMES ROBERTSON"

Comment: Okay thank you much it is greatly appreciated.